# How to remove row and display removed row in textarea except headers?

Tags: javascript, dom, datatables

I am trying to create a webpage that would allow users to send a order request. I want a summary of their order or changes to appear in a textArea using Javascript.

I have tried  storing it in an array, but the textarea value comes back at Undefined. I am either getting a Undefined or [Object HTML] in the textArea

ADD row to Table with ID

```
function addRow(tableID) {


                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


                var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

                for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {


                    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                    row.id = rowCount;





                    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                    newcell.id= i+1;
                    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                        case "text":
                                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";


                                break;
                        case "checkbox":
                                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                                break;
                        case "select-one":
                                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                                break;
    }
}
}


       // DELETE ROW  and try to add to array and set value of textarea


function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var colCount = table.rows.cells.length;
            var rowInfo = new Array();


        for (var i = rowCount - 2; i > 0; i--) {
                var row = table.rows[i];


                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];

                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked ) {
                    for(var m = 1;m<rowInfo.l;m++)
                {
                    rowInfo.push(table.rows[i].cells[m]);
                    document.getElementById("myEmail").value = rowInfo[0];
                }

                    if(rowCount >0){


                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;


                }
            }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert("Please select Part you want to remove");
            }
        }








 <table id="PartTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm table-striped text-center">
               <thead>

                     <th class="text-center">Select</th>
                     <th class="text-center">Part Number</th>
                     <th class="text-center">Old Quantity</th>
                     <th class="text-center">New Quanity</th>
                      <td class="text-center">Price</td>


                </thead><!-- END OF TABLE HEADERS-->

                                        <!-- BEGINNING OF TABLE DATA-->
                                        <tr id="firstrow">


              <td id="selected" ><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" ></td>
            <td id="0"contenteditable="true"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="partNumber"></td>
             <td id="0"contenteditable="true"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="oldquanity"></td>
              <td id="0" contenteditable="true"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="newquantity"></td>
               <td id="0" contenteditable="true">$<input type="text" class="form-control" name="price"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>  

     <div>
<label for="myEmail">EMAIL</label>
      <textarea id="myEmail" class="form-control" rows="3">
</textarea>

                                               </div>
```

/*   I want to put the array in the Textarea so in the future I can send an email. I think I am approaching the problem wrong.. If there are other ways to approacht is problem better . Please Help */

Comment: Is it better to us jQuery?

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to better provide advice, it's a good idea to provide a working example. This can be done on this page or on another site like JSFiddle or CodePen. 

However, at first glance you might want to try converting your array into a string. TextArea values can only display strings.

Comment: Use jQuery if you are quite confident with how you code Javascript. Learn the basics and intermediate techniques before moving forward with a library.

Answer (score 1):

I've made up small example to explain the concept (which is pretty straightforward), sure, you can easily integrate that into your code:

```js
var srcData = [
  {name: 'Mickey', color: 'orange', weapon: 'nunchucks'},
  {name: 'Leo', color: 'blue', weapon: 'sword'},
  {name: 'Don', color: 'purple', weapon: 'bo'},
  {name: 'Raph', color: 'red', weapon: 'sai'},
];

var dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'name', data: 'name'},
    {title: 'color', data: 'color'},
    {
      title: 'weapon', 
      data: 'weapon',
      render: data => data+'<button>x</button>'
    },
  ]
});

$('#mytable').on('click', 'button', function(){
  let rowClicked = dataTable.rows($(this).closest('tr'));
  let msg = Object.values(rowClicked.data()[0]).toString();
  $('#msg').val($('#msg').val()+msg+"\n");
  rowClicked.remove();
  dataTable.draw();
})
```

```css
td button {float: right}
textarea {width: 100%}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="mytable"></table>
    <textarea id="msg"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I have user input in the table.. And the table is a part of a form.. would this still work?

Comment: You can access the value of the input field within, say, third column, like that:: `rowClicked.node().find ('td:eq(2) input').val()`. I'm referring here to my example, because you can try it right off. If you prepare your own jsfiddle or codepen, we can talk in terms of your code. Otherwise, it's not that easy to discuss and troubleshoot something without necessary context.